# Inserting a code block after a div tag using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, class, html

I am a Javascript noob and I need help adding a codeblock after a div.

i want to add code after the following class

```
<div class='post-body entry-content'>
```

So mu JQuery code must be

```
$('post-body entry-content').add('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />');
```

Right ??

If I am wrong please correct me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is incorrect.

- Use the `.` to select by class and join them together if you want to match elements which include all classes.
- To make the image come after, use `after()`.
- Also make sure this code is executed after the element exists. Best way to do that is wrap it with the DOM ready event.

```
$(function() {

    $('.post-body.entry-content')
       .after('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />');

});
```

Comment: can I use this within a function?

Comment: @Hack You can use it wherever you like, including a function.

Comment: @alex I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: @alex now I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } I do not get at why that is being show ?!!

Comment: @alex here is my code `<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
    $(function(){
 $('.debug').after('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/alock+plus+witelist.png" />');
 
 });


var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled';
var _abdNotDetectedFnc = '_disabled';
}
</script>`

Comment: @Hack Exactly what the error says, There is a `}` where the parser doesn't expect it. Remove it.

Comment: @alex http://jsfiddle.net/zH69G/1/ here is the actual code that I use , does the document.write function cause problems . I do that to bypass XHTML in blogger . If you are really kind , here is it's implimentation http://hacktohell.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-correctly-add-google-adsense-ads.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert something after a certain element.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the code block inside the document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.post-body.entry-content').after('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />');
});
```

Comment: Fixed the typo. Copy pasted the code from the post and forgot to change the method name.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want:

```
// inside, before all existing content
$(".post-body.entry-content").prepend('<img src="some image.png" />');

// inside, after all existing content
$(".post-body.entry-content").append('<img src="some image.png" />');

// outside, after
$(".post-body.entry-content").after('<img src="some image.png" />');
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zH69G/).

Comment: here is my code `<script type="text/javascript"> function _enabled() { $(function(){ $('.debug').after('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/alock+plus+witelist.png" />'); }); var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled'; var _abdNotDetectedFnc = '_disabled'; } </script>`

Comment: Not sure you you plan to call/use `_enabled()`. can you edit the question and post further details. In the mean time remove the `$(function () {` wrapper and the corresponding `});`. I believe _enabled function is called sometime after dom is ready so no need to use `$(function)` wrapper.